# where to define transaction boundries in java (@Service or @DAO level), Any Suggestions

Tags: java, spring-transactions

where to define transaction boundries in java (@Service or @DAO level), Any Suggestions

We need to manage transaction between multiple services.

Comment: IMO, transactions should be on the service layer. DAO should not be concerned by this as they merely access data from a datastore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your persistence technology *some* kind of transactions might be needed to persist anything at all. Thus you may want a transaction on a DAO-level for e.g. testing the DAO layer. If e.g. controllers have direct access to DAOs you'll need transactions on DAOs, too.

What you may want to do is declaring a transaction on the service-level *and* the DAO-level reusing a provided transaction.

Read the great [spring reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#transaction) on transactions as well as the [spring data reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.11.0.RELEASE/reference/html/) for ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I recommend to use Transaction in Service, but it depends on....
In case of Service,you will get ability to create batch of actions in the one transaction.

For example start transaction. read, modify more than one entities, update, delete whatever. close transaction.